# Mockito different behavior on subsequent calls to a void method?

Tags: java, mockito

I've got a `save()` method that returns `void`:

```
public void save( MyThing ) throws SaveFailureException { ... }
```

The call to `save()` has retry logic to handle the exception. I want to test it by mocking out the first call to `save()` so that it throws an exception, and the second call should succeed without an exception.

*Mockito* has a nice way to handle successive behavior for non-void methods, e.g.:

```
when( mock.save() ).thenThrow( ... ).thenReturn( ... )
```

How can I do the same with methods that return void?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do that:

```
doThrow(...).doNothing().when(mock).voidMethod();
```

(edit: use `doNothing`, as mentioned by @Rogério)

Comment: don't you mean: `doThrow(...).doReturn(...)` ?

Comment: It should be `doThrow(...).*doNothing()*.when(mock).voidMethod()` instead.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `doNothing()`!